# How to remove number from array based on arguments

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays like this:

```
var arr = ["1", "3" , "4"];
var arr2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
```

I want to remove numbers from second array based on numbers that are available in first array.

I tried this but I am getting wrong values such as 2,4,6,8:

```
theButton.onclick = function removePassedInNumbers(arr){
    for(var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++){
    if(arr2.indexOf(arr[i])){
        arr2.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
    document.getElementById('myNumber').innerHTML = arr2;
}

<input type="button" id="theButton" onclick="removePassedInNumbers(arr)" value="Click here"/>
<p id="myNumber">hey</p>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4hLcanc6/

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear: what output do you expect to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This for loop is incorrect. Even if, as some users has already answered, there are better methods to filter an array, I wanna try to explain why you're doing this loop wrong.

Let's start with the first line

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++)
```

here you're storing in variable `i` your current position in arr2. Ok.

```
if(arr2.indexOf(arr[i]))
```

This is a no-no. `arr[i]` may not exist!! Infact, `arr[3]` is undefined, and you're looking for it the fourth time you enter the loop.
So, let's fix this one:

```
if(arr.indexOf(arr2[i]))
```

Now is ok. We're asking to look inside `arr` to find the value of `arr2[i]`, that will be "1" the first time we jump in the loop, "2" the second time ... and "9" the last time.

Now it will work. To recap:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++){    
  if(arr.indexOf(arr2[i])){
    arr2.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you understand what's going on in your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use filter() method :

```
var arr = ["1", "3" , "4"];
var arr2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
var res = arr2.filter(item => arr.indexOf(item)===-1);
console.log(res); // [ '2', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' ]
```

Or with ES5 :

```
var res = arr2.filter(function(x) {return arr.indexOf(x)===-1});
```

Comment: Can you please provide ES5 syntax? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can update your `function` with something like this

```js
var arr = ["1", "3" , "4"];
var arr2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];

arr.forEach(function(n){
  var index = arr2.indexOf(n); 
  if(index !== -1) arr2.splice(index, 1);
})

console.log(arr2);
```

**Note**: `splice` will change your array `arr2`, if you want a new array without changing the original `arr2` you should use `filter`.

Comment: 1 - `arr2.length` should been `arr.length`. 2 - `arr2.indexOf(arr[i])` should be `arr2.indexOf(arr[i]) !== -1`. 3 -  you need to store the `index` on `arr2` array so you can `splice` it. @Satyadev

Comment: There's not all the changes there. https://jsfiddle.net/a3w0n4yf/ . Also you need to remove the `arr` from the function or properly pass it on the HTML

Comment: Thank you. I like the native js script provided in the fiddle in your comment.